# Character map , python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to obtain a character map :

```
chr:      !   "   #   $   %   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   -   .   /
asc: 32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47
chr:  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   :   ;   <   =   >   ?
asc: 48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63
chr:  @   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O
asc: 64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79
chr:  P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z   [   \   ]   ^   _
asc: 80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95
chr:  `   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o
asc: 96  97  98  99  100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111
chr:  p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z   {   |   }   ~  
asc: 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127
```

I wrote a program for these, but it doen't gives me these panel. I'll post my code too:

```
for a in range(32,128):
   b=chr(a)
   print(b)
   print(a)
```

And the output is:

```
32
!
33
"
34
#
35
$
.........
```

Comment: The required output contains six pairs of `chr` and `asc` lines. So consider a loop of length four.

Comment: @Tichodroma Thank you, I think I can do it now.

Comment: If you did it, please add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
for i in xrange(32, 128, 16):
    print 'chr:\t%s' % '\t'.join(map(chr, [i+j for j in range(16)]))
    print 'asc:\t%s' % '\t'.join(map(str, [i+j for j in range(16)]))
```

**Update** for Python 3:

```
for i in range(32, 128, 16):
    print('chr:\t%s' % '\t'.join(map(chr, [i+j for j in range(16)])))
    print('asc:\t%s' % '\t'.join(map(str, [i+j for j in range(16)])))
```

Comment: Invalid sintax, I think you wrote it in python 2.

Comment: So? Adapt it yourself if you find the solution useful. (Hint: `xrange` is called `range` in python 3).

Comment: I believe `[i+j for j in range(14)]]` should have `range(16)`, not 14.

Comment: @jszakmeister yes indeed. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import pprint
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
>>> c = [a]*3
>>> c
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]]
>>> pprint.pprint(c,width=60)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]]
>>>
```

http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html